# Загрузка данных при Server side rendering через getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

Хочу получить данные при SSR на Nextjs и сохранить их в стейт редакса, через getInitialProps диспатчу экшен, он срабатывает, но страница приходит в браузер без состояния, как пробросить стейт с сервера на клиент?

Или это невозможно и пропсы надо сразу подставлять в шаблон?

Как вообще лучше работать с getInitialProps в Nextjs

```
Index.getInitialProps = async ({ reduxStore }) => {
reduxStore.dispatch(initialize());

 return { };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper - у меня с ним сработало. Здесь объяснение  - https://habr.com/ru/post/323588/
Все это естественно на рутовой страничке _app.js

Асинхронные экшены пробросил через redux-thunk

```
export default withRedux(makeStore)(class MyApp extends App {....
```